# How to copy a file only if a corresponding file exists in Apache ant?

Tags: ant, copy, build.xml

For example :

```
src.dir
---a.py
---a.reqs.py
---b.py
---b.reqs.py
---c.py
dest.dir
```

In this case, only `a.py` and `b.py` should be copied to `dest.dir`.
I have tried -

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}">
<fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*.reqs.py"/>    
<mapper type="glob" from = "*.reqs.py" to = "*.py"></mapper>
</copy>
```

However, this seems to instead copy over the reqs file and rename them, which is not what's required.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't come up before as a question ... couldn't spot a similar one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mappers are used for renames rather than defining dependencies, but you can do both in one task.

This works for me:

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*.py">
    <present targetdir="${src.dir}">
      <mapper type="glob" from = "*.py" to = "*.reqs.py"></mapper>
    </present>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

It's similar to your attempt, but uses a [`<present>` selector](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect) to declare the dependency relationship on the "req" files using a nested mapper.

It says "only copy the *.py files if *.req.py files with the same names are present in the src.dir".

Comment: Thanks, exactly what was needed.